# Counting new levels of a factor per site (R)

Tags: r, dplyr, counting, factors, levels

I need to generate a table counting new levels of a factor per site.
My code is like this

```
# Data creation
f = c("red", "green", "blue", "orange", "yellow")
f = factor(f)
d = data.frame(
  site = 1:10,
  color1= c(
    "red", "red", "green", "green",  "green", 
    "blue","green", "blue", "orange", "yellow"
  ),
  color2= c(
    "green", "green",  "green", "blue","green", 
    "blue", "orange", "yellow","red", "red"
  )
)
d$color1 = factor( d$color1 , levels = levels(f) )
d$color2 = factor( d$color2 , levels = levels(f) )
d
```

It shows me this table

[image: my data]

I need to count how many new colors are in every new site. Only count first time appearing, not duplicated.  Resulting a table like this one.

[image: looking for this output]

Counting not duplicated colors per site is in this figure.
[image: Counting]

Is there a **dplyr** way to find this output?

Comment: Thank you @Nuclear0302704 
I also think with variants fo not *duplicated* or similar commands could be done, but got no success.

Comment: Can yu please clarify what you mean to count "not duplicated per site"? because if you are indeed looking per site, then also in e.g. row 2 both values aren't duplicates.

Comment: Thank you @deschen , 2nd row is 0 because they are no **new colors**.  We counted  in row 1. New color is in row 4 and 7...

Comment: But why is there a new color in row 9? orange is already in row 7 and red already in row 1.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Row 9 should be 0 in newColors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
library(tidyverse)
d %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -site) %>%
  mutate(newColors = duplicated(value)) %>%
  group_by(site) %>%
  mutate(newColors = sum(!newColors)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider()
```

which gives:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 4
    site newColors color1 color2
   <int>     <int> <fct>  <fct> 
 1     1         2 red    green 
 2     2         0 red    green 
 3     3         0 green  green 
 4     4         1 green  blue  
 5     5         0 green  green 
 6     6         0 blue   blue  
 7     7         1 green  orange
 8     8         1 blue   yellow
 9     9         0 orange red   
10    10         0 yellow red
```

Note that this differs for row 9 where you have a `1`, but both colors (orange and red) already appeared in previous rows.

Comment: This is a solution @deschen . Thank you!!!
Of course, I mistake in row 9. More thanks for that !!!

Comment: ok. If the answer is helpful, feel free to upvote and/or flag it as your accepted answer so that others see the problem has a solution.

Comment: I accepted your answer. Thanks